# how to use pabot --testlevelsplit when running parallel execution in robot framework?

Tags: robotframework, parallel-execution

I have a test suite A which contains multiple testcases and I want to perform the parallel execution on test level via pycharm terminal. I came across this command pabot --testlevelsplit but I am getting error. Please help out with the proper way to use it.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: pabot --testlevelsplit \testfolderpath\testsuitename.robot - This is the way I am using it and the error is  Parsing '\testfolderpath\testsuitename.robot' failed: File or directory to execute does not exist.

Comment: and it works fine with " pabot --testlevelsplit \testfolderpath\"  and It started execution for all the testsuites present in the testfolder. But I want to perform it for a particular testsuite.

Comment: From my intuition, I would propose to not prepend a `\\` to the path. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats